# scrollViewDidScroll never called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a Scrollview within View. I want to use the function scrollViewDidScroll to check and update the arrows (left right).

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSLog(@"Did scroll");
    [self updateButtons];
}
```

It seems scrollViewDidScroll won't be called when I scroll left or right. I searched everything but didn't found a solution.

Hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The typical error is that "one does not simply set the delegate of a view". What you have probably forgotten is

```
theScrollView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 25):

I had this "symptom" as well and lost about 2 hours of my life on it.  I clearly had the delegate set correctly...but I did NOT know about setting the **contentSize** property on the scroll view. -.-

If you don't set that property, then the scroll view doesn't think there is anything to scroll to, and therefore will NOT trigger the expected scroll view methods.

Comment: Wow this is mean. Was exactly my problem. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined your UIScrollView in the xib, you can simply do a Ctrl-Drag, from the ScrollView to the Files Owner and set the delegate that way. Probably the easiest way to do it.[image]