# Fixed Header-View at top of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

my question is similar to this question: [make UIView in UIScrollView stick to the top when scrolled up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272847/make-uiview-in-uiscrollview-stick-to-the-top-when-scrolled-up)

How should I modify the code to keep the header fixed at the top WHEN I scroll DOWN.