# UIScrollView one subview stick on top while scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, sticky

We have multiple items in a UIScroll view. While scrolling, we have to set one view in the top as sticky.If we scroll down down its will change to normal position.

We have designed using autolayout, we have tried below link but not working in autolayout, please guide us.

[make-uiview-in-uiscrollview-stick-to-the-top-when-scrolled-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272847/make-uiview-in-uiscrollview-stick-to-the-top-when-scrolled-up)

Comment: Show us what you tried - your current code

Comment: I think You have Set Header In Storyboard using Auto layout so in Scrollview whenever you will scroll it will change there possition. if you want stick there item must be set constraint using code. if you share your code I defenatly help you.